# 96 nonvtec motor convert to vtec and put into a 94 honda del.sol

Tags: honda, engine-swap

Newby to auto industry. What do I need to do to put a 96 1.6  non VTEC motor in a 94 Honda equiped for a 1.6 VTEC?

Comment: First i would buy a 94 vtec motor and then install it.

Comment: There is a lot you'll need to do that cannot be answered in a simple question. I would read up on forums such as honda-tech.com, and come back with more specific questions (eg will I need to modify the chassis to install a JDM B16A2 motor, or will XX ECU work with XX wiring harness).